# can someone explain me why alert.length returns "0" and why Array.length or Object.length returns 1

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer, alert

can someone explain to me why `alert.length` returns "0" and why `Array.length` or `Object.length` returns "1"

```js
console.log('alert.length: '  + alert.length);  // 0
console.log('Array.length: '  + Array.length);  // 1
console.log('Object.length '  + Object.length); // 1
console.log('String.length: ' + String.length); // 1

/* as you see can anyone of you explain me why this works this way */
```

can someone explain this to me. is this behavior mentioned in [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/)

Comment: Probably this: [Function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length property indicates the number of parameters expected by the function.

Just go through https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-len

Why you getting zero in alert.length 
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-alert

Comment: so then why `alert.length` returns `0` because to pass an argument to `alert function` it must atleat have `1` `parameter` so `alert.length` should return `1`

Comment: Please have a look why you getting zero 
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-alert

Comment: I have the same question as @Kevin and I'm not sure how the links answer that. You can call `Array` without passing any arguments as well: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-constructor-array